# Can not create NSURL object because of "|" symbol in url string

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I need to create an object of NSURL from url string like [this](https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&pt=55.1583062965,61.3948104504,pm2rdm%7C55.1583062962,20.232332,pm2rdm&size=600,300). It contains `|` symbol. The problem is that NSURL constructor always returns nil, because of `|` symbol. How can I create this object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is lowercase `l`, not the pipe `|` character.

However, you can use [`stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:) with `NSCharacterSet.URLQue‌​ryAllowedCharacterSet()` to escape invalid characters in the URL:

```
url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQue‌​ryAllowedCharacterSet())
```

--

```
let url = "https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?l=map&pt=55,1583062965,61,3948104504,pm2rdm&size=600,300"    
let escapedURL = url.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQue‌​ryAllowedCharacterSet())
print(NSURL(string: escapedURL))
```